# How to call dynamic values in Azure Functions parameter

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have an Azure Function which triggers on service bus topic and its going to copy data from blob storage to Azure Cosmos Db Table Api. Depending on the file name in Azure Blob storage, the file data will be copied as entity to respective table in Cosmos Db table Api.

Problem: I would like to refer the table name in the code for each file getting copied dynamically and if table does not exist I would be creating one in cosmos db.

So for example i have below code in Azure function:

```
public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("SBTopic", "SBSubscription", Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")] string mySbMsg,
    [CosmosDB(
databaseName: "DBName",
collectionName: "{Dynamic table name}",
ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient client,          
                ILogger log)
{

    try {
         log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
         // I get the variable name which will be my table name. Now refrencing this table name in Cosmos Db

         CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(client);
         if (await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(Dynamic table name)) 
            { log("Created Table named: {0}", Dynamic table name); 
               // start copying entity 
            }
         else
            { log("Table {0} already exists", Dynamic table name); 
              // start copying entity 
            }.
```

In this **Dynamic table name** will be coming from another set of code running in same method. So question is now how do i first handle my Cosmos Db Connection and how do I refer it in the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may check this : http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Dynamic-Binding-in-Azure-Functions-with-Imperative-Runtime-Bindings and try something similar with the cosmos db bindings.

```
 BlobAttribute dynamicBlobBinding = new BlobAttribute(blobPath: $"{path details}/{dynamic property 1}/{dynamic property2}");
```

You can also refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-azure-functions-csharp and check if this would be helpful in this scenario.